# How to target .p elements in dynamic pages (opencart)

Tags: html, css, opencart

I'm trying to figure out how to target a p. element which is a part of a product category description in an opencart shop. Basically, I want to style the product description so the image is on the left and description on the right with 20px padding.

My problem is that I did all that but don't know how target `p` elements when the open cart template file only has div classes for everything else ecxept `p` elements.

Here's the direct link to the [page](http://ceu.kuhada.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=33_62)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can always target a p element with a parent of div.category_description

Comment: As per your requirement and class you used. You can go to http://ceu.kuhada.com/catalog/view/theme/OPC080192_1/stylesheet/stylesheet.css and at line 2073 there is class .cds where you need to add padding like .cds{
margin: 0px 20px 0 20px; float: left; padding-right:20px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
.product-block.product-thumb .product-block-inner .product-details .caption p.desc
```